# Is every absorbing set balanced?

Tags: functional-analysis

I study functional analysis and in my professor's handbook I found these definitions:
Let E be a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ and $X \subset E $.
X is an absorbing set if $\forall x\in E, \exists r>0 \text{ s.t. }\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{K}\text{ s.t. }|\lambda|\leq r,\text{ we have: } \lambda.x\in X$.
X is a balanced set if $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{K}\text{ s.t. }|\lambda|\leq 1,\forall x\in X \text{ we have: } \lambda.x\in X$.
My question might sound dumb, but is every absorbing set is a balanced set? Why? And does that $r$ change every time we choose a different $x\in E$ ?

Comment: Where did you encounter the definition (source?) How does your source define a balanced set, or what is the source of the definition you mean (please include that definition?)  Your three questions require more context, for us better understand your questions.

Comment: For the source, It is mentioned in my professor's handbook. I will add the definition of a balanced set in this handbook.

Comment: I added it. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the update/edit.  Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absorbing means that by dilation, the set $X$ absorbs any element of $E.$ Balanced implies here that $X$ is invariant under rotations (if $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$).

Consider $E = \mathbb{C}$ over the field $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$ and consider as an example $X = B(0,1) \cup B(2,1/2).$
Here $X$ is absorbing, but not balanced.

The $r$ generally depends on $x$. For example, for $x=10$ a value $r<1/10$ works, but for $x=100$, we should take $r<1/100.$

Comment: Thank you for this counterexample! However, I have a few questions in mind.
Are you sure about the invariance under rotations? Isn't a square-shaped set would be balanced in C?
For the absorbing sets, is that r depending on each x of E?

Comment: If you denote $\lambda= e^{i\theta}$ then multiplication by $\lambda$ is rotation over $\theta.$ Note that $|\lambda|=1.$ So being balanced implies that $X$ should be invariant under rotations. In the example $X$ is not invariant under rotations as e.g. $2\in X$ but $2i= 2e^{i\pi /2} \notin X.$

Comment: An example over $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ and $E = \mathbb{R}$ is e.g. $X = [-1,2].$

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very appreciated.